# stop my script focussing on the div I'm fading out when it's not visible on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div, inside which I'm using as a slide show. It all works fine but when the page is scrolled so the slideshow isn't in view, and the fadeIn animation happens then the page auto scrolls to show the animation. Is there anyway to stop this?

I'm really newbie with javascript :(

```
window.setInterval(function(){
            if(fader < <?php echo count($homePageFavs);?>) {//it's not the last image so we can move right
        var newFade = fader;
        newFade++;
        $(".fader_"+fader).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
            $(".fader_"+newFade).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
                // Animation complete
            });
        });
        fader = newFade;
    } else { // loop back to the first one
                    $(".fader_"+fader).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
            $(".fader_1").fadeIn( "slow", function() {
                // Animation complete
            });
        });
        fader = 1;
            }
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: In your code there aren't nothing to scroll to the slideshow. Or you have got another code or you miss to explain better your case.

Comment: I literally just have a div and inside the div are all the images, I'm using that javascript above to switch between those images.

Comment: You can make a http://jsfiddle.com  reproducing the issue. Your code haven't any `scrollTop()` function to scroll automatically, so there's another problem inside. Make a working fiddle with the issue and share it

Comment: And what are you doing in animation methods complete callback???

Comment: Sounds like dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916992/jquery-fadein-cause-a-scroll-top-how-can-i-solve

Comment: http://sprproperties.co.uk/

Comment: On xhich browser? I don't see any unexpected scrolling in chrome on tablet

Comment: I tried adding a container around the images with a fixed height and that's sorted the problem - thanks A Wolff!